# jQuery.Gantt - item label and color not rendered as expected

Tags: jquery, colors, label, bar-chart, gantt-chart

I am trying to render a jQuery.Gantt chart. Everything looks good except that the label and color of each item are not rendered as expected (labels do not show, and all items are in blue although some of them are expected to be show in other colors).

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="gantt" class="gantt"></div>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
<script src="/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery.fn.gantt.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r298/prettify.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(".gantt").gantt({
        source: [{
        name: "Sprint 0",
        desc: "Analysis",
        values: [{
            from: "/Date(1320192000000)/",
            to: "/Date(1322401600000)/",
            label: "Requirement Gathering",
            customClass: "ganttRed"
        }]
        },{
        name: " ",
        desc: "Scoping",
        values: [{
            from: "/Date(1322611200000)/",
            to: "/Date(1323302400000)/",
            label: "Scoping",
            customClass: "ganttRed"
        }]
        },{
        name: "Sprint 1",
        desc: "Development",
        values: [{
            from: "/Date(1323802400000)/",
            to: "/Date(1325685200000)/",
            label: "Development",
            customClass: "ganttGreen"
        }]
        },{
        name: " ",
        desc: "Showcasing",
        values: [{
            from: "/Date(1325685200000)/",
            to: "/Date(1325695200000)/",
            label: "Showcasing",
            customClass: "ganttBlue"
        }]
        },{
        name: "Sprint 2",
        desc: "Development",
        values: [{
            from: "/Date(1326785200000)/",
            to: "/Date(1325785200000)/",
            label: "Development",
            customClass: "ganttGreen"
        }]
        },{
        name: " ",
        desc: "Showcasing",
        values: [{
            from: "/Date(1328785200000)/",
            to: "/Date(1328905200000)/",
            label: "Showcasing",
            customClass: "ganttBlue"
        }]
        },{
        name: "Release Stage",
        desc: "Training",
        values: [{
            from: "/Date(1330011200000)/",
            to: "/Date(1336611200000)/",
            label: "Training",
            customClass: "ganttOrange"
        }]
        },{
        name: " ",
        desc: "Deployment",
        values: [{
            from: "/Date(1336611200000)/",
            to: "/Date(1338711200000)/",
            label: "Deployment",
            customClass: "ganttOrange"
        }]
        },{
        name: " ",
        desc: "Warranty Period",
        values: [{
            from: "/Date(1336611200000)/",
            to: "/Date(1349711200000)/",
            label: "Warranty Period",
            customClass: "ganttOrange"
        }]
        }],
        dow:    ["So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa"],
        navigate: "scroll",
        maxScale: "hours",
        itemsPerPage: 10,
        onItemClick: function(data) {
        alert("Item clicked - show some details");
        },
        onAddClick: function(dt, rowId) {
        alert("Empty space clicked - add an item!");
        },
        onRender: function() {
        if (window.console && typeof console.log === "function") {
            console.log("chart rendered");
        }
        }
    });

    $(".gantt").popover({
        selector: ".bar",
        title: "I'm a popover",
        content: "And I'm the content of said popover.",
        trigger: "hover"
    });

    prettyPrint();
</script>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
.gantt {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 20px auto;
        border: 14px solid #ddd;
        position: relative;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
            border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .bar .fn-label{
        display:none;
    }
    .gantt:after {
        content: ".";
        visibility: hidden;
        display: block;
        height: 0;
        clear: both;
    }

    .fn-gantt {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .fn-gantt *,
    .fn-gantt *:after,
    .fn-gantt *:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .fn-gantt .fn-content {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .fn-gantt .row {
        float: left;
        height: 24px;
        line-height: 24px;
        margin: 0;
    }


    /* === LEFT PANEL === */

    .fn-gantt .leftPanel {
        float: left;
        width: 225px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 20;
    }

    .fn-gantt .leftPanel .fn-label {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 0 0 5px;
        color: #484A4D;
        width: 110px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .fn-gantt .leftPanel .row {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
    }
    .fn-gantt .leftPanel .name, .fn-gantt .leftPanel .desc {
        float: left;
        height: 24px;
        width: 50%;
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
    }

    .fn-gantt .leftPanel .name {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .fn-gantt .leftPanel .fn-wide, .fn-gantt .leftPanel .fn-wide .fn-label {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .fn-gantt .leftPanel .spacer {
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
        width: 100%;
    }




    /* === RIGHT PANEL === */

    .fn-gantt .rightPanel {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .fn-gantt .dataPanel {
        margin-left: 0;
        outline: 1px solid #DDD;
        /* TODO: Replace image with gradient?
        background-size: 24px 24px;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.7) 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(to top, rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.7) 1px, transparent 1px);
        */
        background-image: url(/assets/img/grid.png);
        background-repeat: repeat;
        position: relative;
    }

    .fn-gantt .row.header {
        margin-right: -1px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .fn-gantt .day, .fn-gantt .date {
        overflow: visible;
        width: 24px;
        line-height: 24px;
        text-align: center;
        border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #484a4d;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
        text-align: center;
    }

    .fn-gantt .sa, .fn-gantt .sn, .fn-gantt .wd {
        height: 24px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .fn-gantt .sa, .fn-gantt .sn {
        color: #939496;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .fn-gantt .wd {
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .fn-gantt .holiday {
        background-color: #ffd263;
        height: 24px;
    }

    .fn-gantt .today {
        background-color: #fff8da;
        height: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .fn-gantt .rightPanel .month, .fn-gantt .rightPanel .year {
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
        height: 24px;
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #484a4d;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
        text-align: center;
    }

    .fn-gantt-hint {
        border: 5px solid #edc332;
        background-color: #fff5d4;
        padding: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        z-index: 11;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;
    }

    .fn-gantt .bar {
        background-color: #D0E4FD;
        height: 18px;
        margin: 0 3px 3px 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 10;
        text-align: center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25) inset;
            box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25) inset;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px;
    }

    .fn-gantt .bar .fn-label {
        line-height: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: 100%;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
        color: #414B57 !important;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 11px;
    }

    .fn-gantt .ganttRed {
        background-color: #F9C4E1 !important;
    }
    .fn-gantt .ganttRed .fn-label {
        color: #78436D !important;
    }

    .fn-gantt .ganttGreen {
        background-color: #D8EDA3 !important;
    }
    .fn-gantt .ganttGreen .fn-label {
        color: #778461 !important;
    }

    .fn-gantt .ganttOrange {
        background-color: #FCD29A !important;
    }
    .fn-gantt .ganttOrange .fn-label {
        color: #714715 !important;
    }


    /* === BOTTOM NAVIGATION === */

    .fn-gantt .bottom {
        clear: both;
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .fn-gantt .navigate {
        border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
        padding: 10px 0 10px 225px;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate .nav-slider {
        height: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate .nav-slider-left, .fn-gantt .navigate .nav-slider-right {
        text-align: center;
        height: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate .nav-slider-left {
        float: left;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate .nav-slider-right {
        float: right;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate .nav-slider-content {
        text-align: left;
        width: 160px;
        height: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 10px;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate .nav-slider-bar, .fn-gantt .navigate .nav-slider-button {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate .nav-slider-bar {
        width: 155px;
        height: 6px;
        background-color: #838688;
        margin: 8px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate .nav-slider-button {
        width: 17px;
        height: 60px;
        background: url(/assets/img/slider_handle.png) center center no-repeat;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        margin: -26px 0 0 0;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate .page-number {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 10px;
        height: 20px;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate .page-number span {
        color: #666666;
        margin: 0 6px;
        height: 20px;
        line-height: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate a:link, .fn-gantt .navigate a:visited, .fn-gantt .navigate a:active {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .fn-gantt .nav-link {
        margin: 0 3px 0 0;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        font-size: 0;
        background: #595959 url(/assets/img/icon_sprite.png) !important;
        border: 1px solid #454546;
        cursor: pointer;
        vertical-align: top;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
            border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1) inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1) inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1) inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .fn-gantt .nav-link:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25) inset, 0 1px 0 #FFF;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25) inset, 0 1px 0 #FFF;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25) inset, 0 1px 0 #FFF;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate .nav-page-back {
        background-position: 1px 0 !important;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate .nav-page-next {
        background-position: 1px -16px !important;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate .nav-slider .nav-page-next {
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate .nav-begin {
        background-position: 1px -112px !important;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate .nav-prev-week {
        background-position: 1px -128px !important;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate .nav-prev-day {
        background-position: 1px -48px !important;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate .nav-next-day {
        background-position: 1px -64px !important;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate .nav-next-week {
        background-position: 1px -160px !important;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate .nav-end {
        background-position: 1px -144px !important;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate .nav-zoomOut {
        background-position: 1px -96px !important;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate .nav-zoomIn {
        background-position: 1px -80px !important;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate .nav-now {
        background-position: 1px -32px !important;
    }

    .fn-gantt .navigate .nav-slider .nav-now {
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .fn-gantt-loader {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#bf000000', endColorstr='#bf000000',GradientType=0 );
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        cursor: wait;
        z-index: 30;
    }
    .fn-gantt-loader-spinner span {
        position: absolute;
        margin: auto;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        height: 1em;
        line-height: 1em;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 1em;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .row:after {
        clear: both;
    }
```

So, What is wrong in my code, and how can I fix it? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it! I just need to delete the lines below from my CSS code:

```
.bar .fn-label{
    display:none;
}
```

Besides, I have to call **jquery.fn.gantt.js** file this way:

```
<script src="http://rawgithub.com/taitems/jQuery.Gantt/master/js/jquery.fn.gantt.js"></script>
```